# How to get difference between two immutable Map?

Tags: javascript, frontend, immutability

I have two immutable map:

```
const first = immutable.Map({ one: 1, two: 2 });
const two = immutable.Map({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 });
```

How to get difference ? 
I should get:

```
{ three: 3 } // Map because need merge this data in the feature
```

Comment: If this is a flat object, I think you can get keys as List, then it's easy to get the diference, which will return you the keys that are only present in one of the objects, then you iterate this list to generate a new object getting the values

Answer (score 0):

In immutable 4.0.0-rc.12 you can do

```
const first = Immutable.Map({ one: 1, two: 2 });
const two = Immutable.Map({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3 });
console.log(two.deleteAll(first.keys()).toJS())
```

to achieve similar result
`deleteAll` wasn't a thing in version 3, so I guess you can produce sets from maps keys and intersect them

```
const m1 = new Immutable.Map({foo: 2, bar: 42});
const m2 = new Immutable.Map({foo: 2, bar: 42, buz: 44});


const s1 = Immutable.Set(m1.keys());
const s2 = Immutable.Set(m2.keys());

const s3 = s2.subtract(s1);
const tmp = {};
for (let key of s3.keys()) {
  tmp[key] = m2.get(key);
}

const res = new Immutable.Map(tmp);
console.log(res.toJS());
```